# Drupal 8, hook_preprocess_ page by route

Tags: drupal-8

I have the following code in a Drupal's 8.2 *my_module.module* file.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
     *
     */
    function my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
        if( \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == my.route )
            doSomething();
    }


    function doSomething(){
        //code here
    }
```

My intention is to run some code **only** when the user requests *my.route*.

Does Drupal have any function like this?

```
    function my_route_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
         //code here
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, Drupal 8 doesn't have a function like which you want (preprocess a route) because the idea for the theme preprocess is to preprocess the variables that will be available on your twig template, and preprocess a route doesn't make sense.

In this way, you can follow like you started, preprocessing a page, block, view or etc validating by your route.

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $current_route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
    $route_name = $current_route->getRouteName();

     if($route_name == 'myroute.hook') {
       //your logic here
    }
}
```

You can read more about the available theme preprocess for Drupal 8 on the Drupal doc: [theme.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/8.2.x).

Comment: Just a quick typo correction: it should just be `if` and not `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

No drupal does not have a preprocess function like that.

Actually the hook you uses is not hook_preprocess_page() but hook_preprocess_HOOK() and can be used for more than just pages so it does not know anything about routes. See [hook_preprocess_HOOK() api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x).